# APIs for oil and gas well location/production data?

Tags: geospatial, api, energy

I've been hunting for something like this but haven't found anything yet:

- Well location
- Production

for oil and gas.

Any ideas?

Comment: I judged a student poster at AGU in either 2011 or 2012 on a database collecting info about petrochemical samples ... I can't remember the name of the project though.  You might find something at EarthCube -- they have a specific group for Petrology & Geochemistry : http://workspace.earthcube.org/petrology-geochemistry

Answer (score 3):

Some of the States provides datasets for oil and gas well locations:

**Illinois** (ArcGIS, Shapefiles)
http://certmapper.cr.usgs.gov/data/noga00/natl/spatial/doc/ilcells06g.htm

**Louisiana** (XML)
http://lagic.lsu.edu/data/losco/oil_gas_wells_ldnr_2007_faq.html

**New York** (CSV download)
http://www.dec.ny.gov/energy/1603.html

**Nevada** (University of Nevada, Reno - 2011)
http://www.nbmg.unr.edu/Oil&Gas/NVWellInfo.html

**Texas** Railroad Commission (charge ~$20/dataset)
http://www.rrc.state.tx.us/data/datasets/WellData.php

**Utah**
http://gis.utah.gov/data/energy/oil-gas/

**Production Summaries by State**:
Distribution and Production of Oil and Gas Wells by State
https://explore.data.gov/download/dwne-h7vw/XLS

**ArcGIS** free dataset (CC-BY) for **Alaska 2008**
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ccfcd4a89a234275a18408b9d7fe9fe0

**UK** on/off shore oil wells/rigs (MS-Excel)
https://www.gov.uk/oil-and-gas-digital-data-exchange-format

There are also commercial providers (paid), for example:
*PetroView* http://www.psg.deloitte.com/ProductsPetroviewData.asp